# How to clear temporary data (storage) inside of a cordova project?

Tags: android, cordova, storage

I am using cordova 3.5 and eclipse to develop a mobile application. Inside of an image stream I am downloading 30 images through jquery append (url). The storage information are displayed in the following figure.

[image]

Anyone knows how to clear the "DATA" (19.41MB) category programmatically?

[I have the same issue with IOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26462983/how-to-follow-apples-data-storage-guidelines-by-using-jquery-append-url-in-c), when I try to follow [apples data storage guidelines...](https://developer.apple.com/icloud/documentation/data-storage/index.html)

best

M